# How do you import components having same name on Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm working on a VueJs project and now structuring my router records. I've realized I could be having different components having same name. How do I import them and use them in the route records? How do I make their names unique when configuring the router?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import AllUsers from '../components/Sales/AllUsers'
import AllUsers from '../components/Finance/AllUsers'
...
export default new Router({
routes: [
{
    path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home
},
{
    path: '/sales/users', name: 'sales-users', component: AllUsers
},
{
    path: '/finance/users', name: 'finance-users', component: AllUsers
}
```

I have used a hypothetical example here (since I could as well call the components `SalesUsers` and `FinanceUsers`) but you will agree there are times when components will really have same name. How do I handle that, given that I need to specify the component for each route record?

PS: Slightly new to VueJS, so advice on improvements and best practices is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your exports are [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) you can choose any name during import:

```javascript
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import AllSalesUsers from '../components/Sales/AllUsers'
import AllFinanceUsers from '../components/Finance/AllUsers'
// ...

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/sales/users', name: 'sales-users', component: AllSalesUsers
    },
    {
      path: '/finance/users', name: 'finance-users', component: AllFinanceUsers
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also import the components while defining the routes.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
...
export default new Router({
routes: [
{
    path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home
},
{
    path: '/sales/users',
    name: 'sales-users',
    component: ()=> import('../components/Sales/AllUsers')
},
{
    path: '/finance/users',
    name: 'finance-users',
    component: ()=> import('../components/Finance/AllUsers')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If is not the default export you can use this:

```js
import { AllSalesUsers } from '../components/Sales/AllUsers'
import { AllSalesUsers as AllFinanceUsers } from '../components/Finance/AllUsers'
```